# Getting user home folder through alfresco rest api

Tags: alfresco-webscripts

Using Alfresco web scripts I can login and get ticket but I can't find any script to get user home folder. I can get folders inside another folder using below script:  
   `GET /alfresco/service/slingshot/doclib/doclist/{type}/node/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}`
  But after login I don't know the user home id. Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The userhome onces authenticated is considered to be a root object if you are dealing with classic webscripts.

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/5.0_JavaScript_API#Root_Scope_Objects

You can access it via

var name = userhome.properties.name

Or you can use any of the other properties you may need via the Scripting Node API.

If you are looking for a webscript itself that just returns back the userhome you may need to create your own webscript to access just their User Home information. This can be done quickly and I recommend following this tutorial to learn how to quickly create one that fits what you are looking to do

http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/webscripts/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks, works fine. Is it possible to create script files and place it somewhere inside alresco? Or I always have to create it through alfresco share?